# jQuery vertical animation not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm new to jquery and I working the below program. it involves three colored squares placed on top of each other.

I have managed to get the top square to move horizontally to the end of the screen and back, but I can not get the middle square to move up and down using the existing function. Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background-color: rgb(210,210,210);
}

.block
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
}

#first
{
    background-color: blue; 
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
}

#second
{
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    top:0px;
}

#third
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

and here is the html/JQ part

**JavaScript** *[I have commented out my attempt to get the middle square to move up and down, which is not working]*

```
var sign = "";

function a() {


    var xPos = $("#first").css("left");
    //var yPos = $("#second").css("bottom");


    xPos = parseInt(xPos);
    //yPos = parseInt(yPos);
    if (xPos > 1020) {
        // change direction
        sign = "-";
    } else if (xPos < 0) {
        sign = "";
    }

    //if (yPos > 1020)
    //{
    // sign = "-";
    //}
    //else if (yPos < 0)
    //{
    //sign = "";
    //}
    $("#first").css("left", "+=" + sign + "1");
    //$("#second").css("bottom","-=" + sign + "1");

    console.log("hello");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // this event handler will be executed 
    //when the whole document has loaded 
    setInterval(a, 1 / 60);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block" id="first"></div>

<div class="block" id="second"></div>

<div class="block" id="third"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Andrew Arnold's answer, your logic for the direction flipping needs some attention:

1. Your `sign` variable would flip for either the X or the Y position reaching the limit, which will function fine right now because your limit on both values is `1080`, but if you change that limit for one of them it will lead to erroneous behaviour. I created a `signX` and `signY` variable for each direction.
2. Your logic for flipping `signY` was incorrect because the bottom value was negative, not positive. I changed the logic to properly handle the direction.

Resulting JS:

```
var signX = "";
var signY = "";

function a() {
    var xPos = $("#first").css("left");
    var yPos = $("#second").css("bottom");


    xPos = parseInt(xPos);
    yPos = parseInt(yPos);

    if (xPos > 1020) {
        // change direction
        signX = "-";
    } else if (xPos < 0) {
        signX = "";
    }

    if (yPos < -1020) {
        signY = "-";
    } else if (yPos > 0) {
        signY = "";
    }

    $("#first").css("left", "+=" + signX + "1");
    $("#second").css("bottom", "-=" + signY + "1");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // this event handler will be executed 
    //when the whole document has loaded 
    setInterval(a, 1 / 60);
});
```

See it working at: http://jsfiddle.net/jeo56vou/3/

Answer (score 1):

Just change your CSS for `second` to this:

```
#second
{
    background-color: green;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

Since it doesn't have a `bottom` property in your original code, there's nothing for jQuery to change, so it doesn't move.